# Is a jar of mustard a liquid in American flight?

Tags: hand-luggage

There have been a few questions about makeup and others that are considered liquids, but now I have a friend visiting from Vancouver, BC Canada and he bought a homemade mustard that is similar to Dijon (same bruised mustard seeds, but made in Oregon), and it dawned on me that mustard might be a liquid for international flights from the US to Canada.

It is definitely more than the allowed amount (3oz or so) and in a clear jar.  Is it a liquid?  No websites seem to have an authoritative answer - although there are opinions arguing both ways.

Comment: It is also a food, and I was questioned by U.S. officials as to whether I am carrying any food (on an international flight).

Comment: **It's liquid enough for TSA.**  That the subsequent flight is international is irrelevant.  However, you must declare it to CBSA as food and being homemade brings a notable chance it will not be allowed.

Comment: Seconding @Johns-305... when it is not a solid, it qualifies; either pulled out for scanning when 100ml or less, or over and in checked baggage, as most female travellers can attest (lotions, creams, makeup, potions).

Comment: Note that the TSA website says that the "liquids" rule applies to ["liquids, aerosols, gels, creams and pastes."](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule)  It's a lot clearer from this list that the rule applies to mustard.

Answer (score 7):

Normal mustard is a liquid.
It can be transported in hold luggage, the luggage you hand in before the flight.

But if in hand luggage, the bag you take in the plane yourself, it can only be in small amounts and in your liquids bag.
That is maximum containers of 3.4 oz, (3 oz is the safe amount) and all of the containers have to be in the one quart plastic (ziplock) bag.
(That is 100ml for the individual containers and a one liter bag, for those who are metric.)

See the rules [on the TSA website here.](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-3-1-1-liquids-rule)
Mustard is about in the same range of fluidity as toothpaste, I think.

Only powdered mustard can be transported in hand luggage in bigger amounts.

As noted in the comment on the question, **food items can be a problem** when crossing national and sometimes already state boundaries.
You will have to tell the customs people that you transport food and if unlucky you will have to leave it behind, as not allowed. (I can not be sure whether it is allowed or not.)

Comment: Kindly, what is powered mustard - because I can ask the person who makes it for something like this?

Comment: @Mikey: I'm sure he meant powDered, aka mustard powder (=dry). But I too would love to have 'powered'.

Comment: Indeed, powdered mustard, (which is a mix of gound mustard seed and other ingredients.) And while it is safe for hand luggage, it is not any better for customs/border security on arrival.

Comment: I've been advised that petroleum jelly, which is quite thick, is considered a liquid for this purpose, so mustard will certainly be considered to be a liquid, too.

Comment: +1. I've even had a tube of mustard confiscated by a European equivalent of the TSA.